# The Maximum URI length of 2083 was exceeded

Tags: silverlight

I have created one Silverlight application. In that I have taken one entity framework model at server side, I have a no of clients list at client side and I want to pass that list to server side when I tried to pass approx 15 to 20 clients it will give me correct out put but when I tried to pass more than it it will give me error like:

> The maximum URI length of 2083 was exceeded

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the POST method instead, where the URI length is not important.

```
[Query(HasSideEffects=true)]
```